# UIView block animation: how to put view back in initial state without a strange effect?

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, xamarin.ios

i've succesfully animated a simple rectangle view on the main screen (using `UIView.Animate`) by setting its Transform property, using rotations and translations.

In the end of the animation, i run another animation to put the view in its initial state: i set the transform property to an identity transform.

It works, but instead of starting at the current location, the animation moves abruptly the view by about 50 points, then it moves the object back to its initial position.

I tryed to set some flags: `BeginFromCurrentState`, `ShowHideTransitionViews`, `OverrideInheritedDuration` without success.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it ?

Comment: maybe that will help, not sure because of monotouch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360402/why-are-animations-on-bounds-of-an-uilabel-only-working-when-increasing-the-size

Comment: definitively not a duplicate, as lots of searching never lead to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the auto reverse option to return the animation to its initial state:

```
UIView.Animate(2f, 0f, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, () => { }, null);
```

Comment: well ... it is not a simple animation. It is a combination of animations which do not occur at the same time. I need to choose by code when it goes back to its initial state. And not using the same animation.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535647/uiview-animation-jumps-at-beginning

Comment: Thank you Krumelur, that's it !!!! Update your answer and it will be marked as the solution.

Comment: A remark: Autoreverse MUST be combined with Repeat. It won't do what you think without.