# Glitch when interactively dismissing modal

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

We have run into this issue when implementing interactive dismissal of a modal view controller (dragging modal down should dismiss it) via `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

Setup:

1. setup `UIViewController` embedded in `UINavigationController` with at least one button in `UINavigationBar`
2. modally present another `UIViewController` embedded in `UINavigationController` with at least one button in `UINavigationBar`
3. setup `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on modaly presented `UINavigationController` to drive `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`
4. drag modal down "holding" it by point on `UINavigationBar`

Issue:

- while slowly dragging down, animation glitches causing modal view to jump up and down
- glitch only appears when :

  1. both `UINavigationBar`s have at least one button on them
  2. you "hold" modal by the point on `UINavigationBar`

Minimal example can be downloaded from [github repo](https://github.com/jakubvano/DismissTest).

Has anyone come accross such an issue? Are there any workarounds? Is there some flaw in our setup?

**Update**

Issue has been simulated on running project above on iPhone 5 simulator with `iOS 9.3`, `OSX 10.11.4`, compiled with Xcode `7.3.1`.

**Update 2**

Further investigation showed, that issue is probably not in the animation: For some reason in given setup `pan.translationInView(view)` is returning unexpected values which causes animation to jump.

**Partial workaround**

Based on Vladimir's idea we partially fixed the issue by overriding `hitTest` method of `UINavigationBar`:

```
class DraggableNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event) else { return nil }

        if view is UIControl || pointIsInsideNavigationButton(point) {
            return view
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    private func pointIsInsideNavigationButton(point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        return subviews
            .filter { $0.frame.contains(point) }
            .filter { String($0.dynamicType) == "UINavigationItemButtonView" }
            .isEmpty == false
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Can't see any glitches either on my iPhone 6 or in the iOS Simulator for iPhone 6.

Comment: NO issue in above code.work like charms

Comment: can share exact issue with me.Which OS type and xCode version and deployment target etc.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the glitch. It only happens when starting the pan from the `UINavigationBar`. Dragging down, the animation jumps back to 0%, then back to the intended 1-2%. The same pattern happens when cancelling the dismissal, after you hit 0%, it jumps back to 1-2%, then back to 0%.

Things that remove the glitch: 
1. Removing the `UIBarButtonItem` from the modal VC
2. Removing the `UIBarButtonItem` from the presenting VC
2. Commenting out the `modalPresentationStyle` assignment

Comment: @bsmith11 Yep, that is the glitch I'm describing. Unfortunatelly, none of the solutions you've mentioned is applicable for our case: commenting out `modalPresentationStyle` causes background view controller to disappear and we need to have buttons on both navigation bars.

Comment: @HiteshSurani I've added system specs on which I can reproduce the issue

Comment: @JAKUB No issue in your exiting code while run using above configration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting glitch. I found a partial solution of this problem few days ago, and since nobody found a full solution, I'll post this, maybe it will be helpful.

If you override `hitTest` method of `UINavigationBar` you can get rid of this issue when you dragging modal by holding on `UINavigationBar`:

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    override public func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        guard let view = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event) else { return nil }

        if view.isKindOfClass(UIControl) {
            return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately if you drag modal by holding on `UIBarButtonItem` on `UINavigationBar`, glitch still be present.

You can also try another approach.

As you noticed, `pan.translationInView(view)` returns incorrect values which causes animation to jump.
You need to compare this value to `y` coordinate of modal view during dragging. You can get this value by checking presentation layer of the modal view controller:

```
...

let translation = pan.translationInView(view)

if let layer = view.layer.presentationLayer() {
            print(layer.frame.origin.y)
}

...
```

You can see that when `pan.translationInView(view)` starts to show wrong value, `layer.frame.origin.y` still will be correct in that moment. You can compare these two values and find the pattern when value is incorrect, and change it to correct by adding few points to `translation.y` value.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I ended up overriding `hitTest`, but also allowed taps on back buttons (surprisingly they are not `UIControl`). Reacting to difference of `translation` and `presentationLayer` would be quite tricky, as one would have to account for different  dragging speeds and direction changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete solution but I was able to reduce the glitch by certain amount. I could reproduce this issue on iPhone 5s with `iOS 9.3.2` [by dragging down the screen holding Navigation Bar]

The problem seems to be in the `UIView.animateWithDuration` block of `DismissalAnimator`. By commenting out the delay and options i.e keeping them to the defaults you can reduce the jumping of the view. You could also try and check for diffrent `UIViewAnimationOptions` for which you get minimum jump.

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
        animations: {
            dismissedView.frame = finalFrame
        },
        completion: { _ in
            let didComplete = !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(didComplete)
        }
   )
```

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535647/uiview-animation-jumps-at-beginning) which seems to be dealing with same issue you are facing. And the responses varying from disabling auto layout, putting `layoutIfNeeded` in animation block [tried, both didn't work].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, changing `.CurveLinear` causes animation to desynchronize from finger movement. Also, given how specific this issue is (buttons in `UINavigationBar`, dragging by point in `UINavigationBar`) i dont think that linked question is related, but will check it out.